# ffmpeg streaming RAW TS over rtp

Tags: ffmpeg

I have a TS file, I want to blindly send that TS over RTP, using the following ffmpeg cmdline strip all but A/V, I need the TS payload sent over RTP to include all that is in the original TS ( Captions, SCTE-35, ... )

ffmpeg cmdline used (sending over only A/V) `ffmpeg -y -re -i $(Input TS) -c copy -f rtp_mpegts rtp://$(some IP):$(Port)`

Can I use ffmpeg to blindly stream a TS file over RTP w/o stripping anything?

Comment: You should be able to map video, audio, subtitle, and data e.g. -map v:0 -map a:1 -map s:0 -map d:0

Answer (score 0):

No, even with `-c copy` it will still modify the transport stream. Use VideoLAN's [multicat](https://www.videolan.org/projects/multicat.html) tool instead.